# U-boot cross compilation: why isn't make using chosen toolchain?

Tags: makefile, cross-compiling, u-boot, toolchain

I have an odd problem, that I have noticed. For the purpose of building ancient uboot (2012.10), I am using an external toolchain (uClibc-ng). I am building ARM target. Here's the command that I am using:

```
PATH='/home/build/src/build/x-tools/armv7a-g4.9.2-lnx3.2.69-uClibc-ng-1.0.22/install/arm-onie-linux-uclibcgnueabi/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin' make CROSS_COMPILE=arm-onie-linux-uclibcgnueabi-
```

The build commences, but I have accidentally noticed, that the external toolchain is *not* being used. I have verified that by adding few lines to u-boot Makefile:

```
+GCCVERSION = $(shell gcc --version | grep ^gcc | sed 's/^.* //g')
+ifeq "$(GCCVERSION)" "7.5.0"
+$(error *** IT DOES NOT SEEM LIKE YOU ARE USING CROSS-COMPILER TOOLCHAIN! ***)
+endif
```

It is odd, as analyzing logs it seems obvious, that 'CROSS_COMPILE=' prefix is not being used. I have tried exporting both PATH and CROSS_COMPILE to environment, but it didn't work either.

I am building it in Docker container, on Ubuntu-18.

What am I missing ?

Comment: How do you know what the make variable `GCCVERSION` is set to?  Maybe it's not set here or not set to what you think it is.  You can add `$(info GCCVERSION = $(GCCVERSION))` to see its value.

Comment: @MadScientist Good question. I have accidentally cut the patch. I have edited my question an added full patch.

Comment: Interestingly, I have added $(info..) clause similar to what you have suggested into config.mk in main U-boot dir, to check whether CC (and so on) variable is set to desired value.. and it is. So it must be overriden somewhere else :-( That is really weird..

Comment: You don't actually say what the result of your test is.  Are you expecting `7.5.0`, or not?  And when you run the build do you see the error message, or not?  And when you say "is set to the desired value" is "7.5.0" the "desired value" that you see?

Comment: Sometimes external toolchains use different program names, so not just `gcc`.  Most likely your makefile doesn't use `gcc` anyway, it probably uses the value of the variable `CC`, which  might be something different.  You also might have to do the info check inside a recipe, rather than at the global level, since some later code could change these values.

Comment: OK, I realized what you mean. I was testing against GCC instead of CC which is why I got the wrong result. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The question was well.. not very smart. Instead of:
(..)
+GCCVERSION = $(shell gcc --version | grep ^gcc | sed 's/^.* //g')
(..)

I should have tested against:
+GCCVERSION = $(shell $(CC) --version | (..))

Basically I was calling GCC instead of $CC that would be set to actual cross compiler.